# x11 - how to set _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

I use XCreateSimpleWindow to create x11 window. xprop shows following allowed actions for my window:

```
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_STICK, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
```

What happens if I don't set them explicitly (like above) ? A window has a default list which contains all of them ? How to set them explicitly ?

**Edit1**
Here is example code which sets only one allowed action:

```
Atom aa = XInternAtom(d, "_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS", False);
Atom close = XInternAtom(d, " _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE", False);
XChangeProperty(d, w, aa, XA_ATOM, 32, PropertyNewValue, (unsigned char*)&close,  1);
```

Window manager still let me move or resize window so maybe I should send some client message ? I want to have a window which allows only for close actions.

Answer (score 2):

1) no, by default window does not have properties, but window managers often set some default values. Try to run your program without WM to see difference

2) use "ChangeProperty" request. Window property is some data associated with window + a little bit of metadata: name (atom) and type (atom). If size of data is more than single type would need it's assumed you have array of those. For example, atom is just 32 bit unsigned int. If you see 8 bytes property of type atom, you interpret content as two atoms. See [XChangeProperty](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XChangeProperty.html) documentation if you are using xlib

Comment: if you want your window to be non-resizeble it's better to use WM_NORMAL_HINTS property - see http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#NORESIZE